# Show that it could be that $[LK:K] \lt [L: L\cap K]$

Tags: field-theory

How could it be that $[LK:K] \lt [L: L\cap K]$?

A simple Venn diagram (indicating overlap of the fields) of an $L$ and a $K$ field seems to indicate that the part of $L$ which isn't in $L\cap K$ is *exactly equal to* the part of the whole graph which isn't in $K$. How could one be less than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ be an irreducibel polynomial of degree $3$ possessing exactly one real root $\alpha$. Let $\beta=a+bi$ be one of the other roots and assume that $a\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K:=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $L:=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. Then $K\cap L=\mathbb{Q}$ and $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=[L:\mathbb{Q}]=3$. However $KL=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, hence $[KL:K]=2$.